# The provider provider.aws does not support resource type "aws_appconfig_application"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to create an AWS AppConfig Application using Terraform resource [aws_appconfig_application](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appconfig_application)

When I try to apply it, it says `Error: Invalid resource type`
 `The provider provider.aws does not support resource type "aws_appconfig_application`

Any idea what's going on here? AppConfig is clearly available in Oregon region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **upgrade your AWS provider**. The support for `aws_appconfig_application` was added in [v3.50](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v3.50.0)